# ionic 2 along with http calls from mysql + php backend

Tags: php, mysql, http, ionic2

I want to know if there is a possibility to bind front-end ionic2 with backend mysql. I tried a lots of methods, but, none of them works. So, can someone give an example of a log in auth with database or something, or a link to a good tutorial.

Comment: Did you mean updates in the database to be automatically updated in the front end or is it only the login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way where you can do this is, you need to develop **Restful API** where it interacts with the MySQL database and use that API to fetch and put data (CRUD) from your Ionic 2 app.

I have done this kind of integration and it works perfectly.

**Update:**

***auth.ts*** (provider)

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthenticationData {

    authenticationEndPoint: string = "url";

      constructor(public http: Http) {
        }

      //login
      loginUser(username: string, password: string): Observable<data-type> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
        let body = '';
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let url = this.authenticationEndPoint + encodeURI(username) + '&password=' + encodeURI(password);

        return this.http.post(url, body, options)
          .map(this.extractData)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }


  //to extract data
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  //to handle error
  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: would u give an example or a link to some tutorial please?? !

Comment: Do you know how to develop PHP restful API?

Comment: yes, everything i did beside sign in and login are working fine , i just need the login.ts and signup.ts

Comment: Do you know how to use ionic providers to connect backend API?

Comment: have you an exmple ?

Comment: i know all this, it has static data , i want to know how to do sign up and login with http requests ...

Comment: Please see my post above.